# (String) or .toString()?

Tags: java, casting

I have a method with an `Object o` parameter.

In this method, I exactly know there is a `String` in "o" which is not null. There is no need to check, or do something else. I have to treat it exactly like a `String` object.

Just curious - what is cheaper - cast it to `String`, or use `Object.toString()`?
Or is it same by time-/cpu-/mem- price?

Update:
The method accepts `Object` because it's the implementation of an interface. There is no way to change the parameter type.

And it can't be `null` at all. I just wanted to say that I do not need to check it for null or emptyness.  In my case, there is always a nonempty string.

Comment: In .NET world, we measured it and ToString() is faster. Given the reason why this is so, the same is almost certainly true of a jitting JVM.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**casting to a String is cheaper** since that doesn't require an external function call, just internal type checking.

Comment: Have you tested it across multiple JREs? I've seen surprising results for exaclty this situation in .NET. Realistically I doubt that the performance will matter in real life - but casting is better from a defensive coding perspective.

Comment: The method call should get inlined. Using generics to remove the (explicit) cast would be bestest.

Comment: @Jon Skeet : I agree that the difference in performance won't be much.

@Tom Hawtin : Since the type of the object that will be received is not known at compile time, I cannot see how the method call can get inlined. Can you plz clarify ?

Comment: @euphoria83: Inlined by the JIT compiler, not by javac.

Comment: Actually, no, method can not be inlined. Type is only known to be Object, and actual implementation depends on runtime type.
Which one is faster still depends on implementation, but as far I remember (I actually did test it with microbenchmark at one point), casting appears to be faster. This is not an obvious answer tho: type checking is not always faster. For String type it can be since it's an object (not interface), and final one at that.

Comment: Wanted to comment against using `Casting to a String` while doing a code review and reached this SO question. Good to know :)

Answer (score 51):

I would use a cast. That validates your "knowledge" that it's a string. If for whatever reason you end up with a bug and someone passes in something other than a string, I think it would be better to throw an exception (which a cast will do) than continue to execute with flawed data.

Answer (score 39):

According to [Silly performance musings: x.toString() vs (String)x](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2008/12/entry_119.html)

> In thend end, results are surprisingly
>   clear: **it is at least twice as fast
>   to cast Object to String than to call
>   Object.toString()**

Comment: I ran that code now, the difference is negligible (Mac, Java 8)

Answer (score 9):

If you know the Object o is a String, I'd say just cast it to a String and enforce it that way.  Calling toString() on an object that you know for sure is a String might just add confusion.

If Object o might be anything other than a String, you'll need to call toString().

Comment: This is the correct answer for me.  Why?  Because casting `(string)Registry.GetValue...` throws an exception for trying to cast an Int32 object, whereas `Registry.GetValue...ToString()` works as expected.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't be too concerned by the performance, if this operation is done even just a few thousand times a second - there's no tangible difference.

I would, however, be concerned of "knowing" the input. You have a method that accepts an `Object` and you should treat it as such, i.e. you shouldn't  *know* anything about the parameter, other than it adheres to the `Object` interface, which happens to have a `toString()` method. In this case, I would strongly suggest using that method instead of just assuming anything.

OTOH, if the input is *always* either  `String` or `null`, just change the method to accept `String`s, and check explicitly for `null`s (which you should do anyways whenever dealing with non-primitives...)

Comment: I said that my question has no valueable meaning :) Im just curious what is *theoretically* cheaper. But thanx anyway

Comment: The cost will depend on how efficient the VM is at virtual method calls vs type checking. That's implementation-specific.

Answer (score 2):

Given that the reference type is an Object and all Objects have a toString() just call object.toString(). String.toString() just returns this.

- toString() is less code to type.
- toString() is less bytecode.
- casting is an expensive operation VS a polymorphic call.
- the cast could fail.
- Use String.valueOf( object ) which just calls object.toString() if its not null.

Answer (score 1):

There cannot be a 'null string in o'.  If o is null, it does not contain a null string, it is just null.  Just check o for null first.  If you <s>cast</s> or call ToString() on null you will crash.

Comment: Casting null will not crash. It will not even throw a NullPointerException, it will just call null to the new type. :)

Answer (score 1):

If what you have in "o" is a String then there is not much of a difference (likely the cast is faster, but that is a VM/Library implementation thing).

If "o" may not be a String but it is supposed to be a String then the cast is what you want (but you should make the method take a String instead of an Object).

If "o" could be any type then you have to use the toString - but be sure to check for null first.

```
void foo(final Object o)
{
    final String str;

    // without this you would get a class cast exception
    // be wary of using instanceof though - it is usually the wrong thing to do
    if(o instanceof String)
    {
        str = (String)o;
    }    
}
```

or

```
void foo(final Object o)
{
    final String str;

    // if you are 100% sure that o is not null then you can get rid of the else
    if(o != null)
    {
        str = o.toString();
    }
}
```

I'd rather code the last one as:

```
void foo(final Object o)
{
    final String str;

    if(o == null)
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("o cannot be null");
    }

    str = o.toString();
}
```

Comment: The first 2 snippets won't really compile (the `final` variable might not have been initialized). You need an `else` that will either throw an exception or initialize `str` to something.

Answer (score 1):

I found oddly that the cast was slower than the vtable lookup implied by the tostring call.