# Is it better to do toString() or cast the Object to String

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(String) or .toString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676363/string-or-tostring)

I have an Object. Is it better to do like this

```
 final String params = myObject.toString();
```

or

```
 final String params =(String)myObject;
```

Comment: What do you mean with better?

Comment: You have left out any information about context.

Comment: Exactly, those are apples and oranges. `toString()` and cast are two different things.

Comment: How about `final String params = String.valueOf(myObject);`

Comment: Since **Java 7**, [java.util.Objects.toString()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object)) provides a succinct (null-safe) way to turn *any* object (String, non-String, or null) into a string representation. There is a version with a default string (e.g. "") if you don't want the default "null" string representation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ToString will work with all objects (as long as they are not null). If you cast to a String then the object has to be a String, otherwise it will fail. So my guess is that you want a toString() call, but it depends on what you want to do!

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you're trying to do.

When you cast the object to string like `(String)myObject` you're actually trying to convert the object to a string, so you can get the class cast exception.

However, when calling `myObject.toString` you get a logical representation in `String` format of that object and it depends on implementation of `toString()` method of that object.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `(String)request.getAttribute("buyertosellerpersoni d")` `request.getAttribute("buyertosellerpersonid")` returns you an object which you typecast into a String object. Incase the object that you're trying to typecast isn't actually a String object, you'll get a ClassCastException. Make sure that you always set the attribute "buyertosellerpersonid" with a String value.

When you use `request.getAttribute("buyertosellerpersonid").toString()`
the `toString()` method of the object returned by `request.getAttribute("buyertosellerpersonid")` is called.

Now it depends on the implementation of the `toString()` method of this object as to what it will return. If it is a string that you've put in the attribute "buyertosellerpersonid" then you'll get the String value. If it is anything else, then you'll get the unsigned hexadecimal representation of its hashcode.

It is always a better idea to typecast the object. This makes sure that you always get the correct object, and it will throw an exception otherwise. You must catch such exceptions to ensure correct functioning of your program.

Answer (score 0):

(String)myObject works fine only if myObject is instance of class String.

In the case of myObject.toString() calls toString() method of class myObject. toString method is inherited from Object class.

Answer (score 0):

It is totally irrelevant and pointless
performance questions to worry about.

Who reallycares? The chances of it making any difference to your overall
algorithm are vanishingly small. Use the one that makes most sense in
your code.

One more thing , There is a difference in the two, you can only cast if object really is a String
object whereas you can call toString() on any Object, not just a String.