# Converting a Cassandra UUID object to PHP string

Tags: php, cassandra

Both of these produce a string from a Cassandra UUID object:

```
(string)$uuidObject
$uuidObject->__toString()
```

Is there a consensus on which is preferred? I'm interested in performance (I *assume* they're the same because __toString() is being called implicitly with the cast), future-proofing, code readability, etc. Or, is/are there another alternative(s)?

Comment: [Unsure if this is also true for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/a/676386/1790644).

Comment: I forgot, there's also "$uuidObject->uuid()", but I don't like this because (IMHO) it doesn't strongly indicate that what I'm creating is a string.

Comment: Preferably you do not directly invoke magic methods.